# Trying to migrate a JBoss quickstart tutorial to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have been working through some of the JBoss quickstart tutorials. Currently, I am trying to adapt the greeter tutorial ( that is found here -http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/greeter/) so that I can replace the default H2 database with mysql. I have made the necessary configuration changes to the standalone.xml file. I have created a module and placed the connector jar alongside it. I have also changed the project's persistence.xml file. However, when I run the project I am getting a number of errors. Please could someone take a look at the log file below and try to discern what may be causing the problem. Please note I have pasted the logs of the errors from the console. Under that I included a paste of the standalone.xml and the persistence.xml and the greeter-quickstart-ds.xml. I have the code hosted on GIT here - https://github.com/bosra/greeter. Thanks in advance

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS] 

23:59:49,141 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 2660ms - Started 135 of 209 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 70 services are passive or on-demand)

23:59:50,443 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implClass=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.MavenDependencyResolver'
23:59:50,445 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ConfigurableArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.spi.Configurable'
23:59:50,450 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.GenericArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
23:59:50,451 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
23:59:50,452 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=UNKNOWN' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.GenericArchive'
23:59:50,453 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.SerializableView'
23:59:50,455 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.JavaArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
23:59:50,456 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
23:59:50,457 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive'
23:59:50,458 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'
23:59:50,459 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarExporter'
23:59:50,460 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'
23:59:50,461 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.jar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ZipImporter'
23:59:50,463 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'
23:59:50,464 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarImporter'
23:59:50,465 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.WebArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
23:59:50,466 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.war' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
23:59:50,474 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive'
23:59:50,474 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.tar.TarGzExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'
23:59:50,475 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.TarGzExporter'
23:59:50,476 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.serialization.ZipSerializableViewImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.serialization.ZipSerializableView'
23:59:50,478 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.ExplodedImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ExplodedImporter'
23:59:50,479 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.ResourceAdapterArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
23:59:50,480 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.rar' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
23:59:50,480 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.ResourceAdapterArchive'
23:59:50,492 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.ExplodedExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ExplodedExporter'
23:59:50,493 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.spec.EnterpriseArchiveImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
23:59:50,494 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.ear' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
23:59:50,495 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'archiveFormat=ZIP' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive'
23:59:50,496 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.tar.TarGzImporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'
23:59:50,497 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extension=.tar.gz' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.TarGzImporter'
23:59:50,502 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'implementingClassName=org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.ZipExporterImpl' for service type 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ZipExporter'
23:59:50,553 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary


23:59:50,774 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
23:59:50,782 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
23:59:50,790 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
23:59:50,799 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
23:59:50,803 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ticket-monster.war
23:59:50,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'ticket-monster.war#primary'
23:59:50,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [jboss/datasources/ticket-monsterDS]
23:59:50,882 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
23:59:50,882 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
23:59:50,886 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: loginDatabase
    ...]
23:59:51,146 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
23:59:51,146 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
23:59:51,147 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
23:59:51,414 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.5 (SNAPSHOT 20111202) for context '/jboss-as-numberguess'
23:59:51,582 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
23:59:51,582 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
23:59:51,585 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
23:59:51,591 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
23:59:51,593 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
23:59:51,597 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
23:59:51,598 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
23:59:51,601 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
23:59:51,601 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
23:59:51,617 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
23:59:51,617 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
23:59:51,621 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
23:59:51,630 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
23:59:51,633 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
23:59:51,633 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
23:59:51,706 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
23:59:51,739 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) META-INF/validation.xml found. Parsing XML based configuration.
23:59:52,575 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Using org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator as validation provider.
23:59:52,576 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as message interpolator.
23:59:52,577 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Using org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver as traversable resolver.
23:59:52,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Using org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl as constraint factory.
23:59:52,603 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
23:59:52,609 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
23:59:52,634 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
23:59:52,636 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH000230: Schema export complete
23:59:52,638 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-3) Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
drop sequence hibernate_sequence [90036-161]


23:59:52,697 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
23:59:52,700 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
drop sequence hibernate_sequence [90036-161]

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_18-bin_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDS] 

23:59:53,950 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,951 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,952 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,953 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,953 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,954 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,955 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,956 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,957 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDSjboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_18-bin_jarMissing[jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDSjboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_18-bin_jar]"]}}}
23:59:53,960 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
23:59:53,961 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
```

Comment: You're welcome. Next time **don't post a code wall**.

Answer (score 1):

This line in persistence.xml:

```
<jta-data-source>"java:jboss/datasources/mysql"</jta-data-source>
```

Remove the double quotes so that it is:

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mysql</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: I don't see any whitespace in the persistence file..But thanks for the input

Comment: No it isn't that either. JBoss server won't even run now.

Comment: Not a very helpful response. What exception is JBoss throwing now?

Comment: Thanks for your help James I will edit the original post now with the new errors been shown

Answer (score 1):

The latest exception suggests your MySQL jar is not set correctly on classpath for JBoss. I would double check how you have installed the jar as a module of JBoss 7. This link might help: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7#Installing_a_JDBC_driver_as_a_module

Comment: James, thanks again. I went through the tutorial and I am pretty sure that I have the module.xml file correct. I downloaded the connector/j file. I unzipped the file and I took just the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar component from the extracted file and placed it alongside the module.xml in a folder structure com/mysql/main. I am just wondering is there a problem with the "greeter-quickstart-ds.xml" file. The project I am working with here is a JBoss quickstart tutorial that I am trying to migrate to mysql. Is it possible that it only should have a persistence file?

Comment: https://github.com/bosra/greeter - All of the code is on GIT at that address cheers

Comment: I should mention too that the index file is not appearing in the com/sql/main directory either

Comment: @bosra can you post the full structure of your JBoss module directory please?

Comment: Hey James, I have pasted some more information in another thread. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181824/how-to-incorporate-mysql-into-jboss-quickstart-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The exception is

> cannot parse XML (JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration)

In your file "greeter-quickstart-ds.xml", i see a`</datasources>` without a `<datasources>`. Please check if your XML is correct.

Comment: Thanks..but I do have datasources tag there. I forgot to paste it with the rest of the code

Comment: Can you paste in the entire contents of the files please